# Cordova/Phonegap does not recognise FileTransfer

Tags: cordova

I am working on a cross- platform app that should download a zipped file from a web server via url and save it on the sdcard. The phonegap documentation gives this as the method to download

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

    fileTransfer.download(url,
            filePath, 
            function(entry) {
                alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
            }, 
            function(error) {
                alert("download error.");
                console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
            });
```

but I keep getting an error that FileTransfer was not defined. My script tag looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
```

I have installed the latest version of cordova. I tried referencing older versions 2.5.0 and 2.2.0 and phonegap 1.4.1 but the device seemed never to get ready, hence the function that should be loaded onDeviceReady was never called.

I figure that the js file I have included for doesn't define FileTransfer. Could someone please tell me which version of cordova/ phonegap I can use to perform FileTransfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by using Cordova 1.7 instead of 3.0 which is what I was using before. Other errors encountered by the ZipPlugin were also solved by using the lower version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add file-transfer as plugin to your cordova project.

From http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html:

"As of version 3.0, Cordova implements device-level APIs as plugins"